# Display WordPress post content images and text separately

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking at the WordPress blog and I'm trying to figure out how to display the image and text separately when displaying the content. The reason I want to do this is because I want to create a custom layout, and I need to be able to move the image around without grabbing all the text at the same time. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

**Example of what i've already got: (UPDATED)**

```
<?php 

 require('blog/wp-blog-header.php'); 

?>

<?php 

$args = array( 'numberposts' => 2, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
echo '<ul id="latest_posts">';

foreach 
    ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); 

echo get_content_without_tag( apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() ), 'a' );

$image = get_tag_without_text( apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() ), 'a' );
?> 
<li>
<strong>
    <?php the_date(); ?>
</strong>
<br />

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a>
<p>
    <?php echo $image[0]; ?>
</p>
</li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

**ERROR:**

> Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given
>   in
>   /hsphere/local/home/poulaum/isosec.co.uk/blog/wp-includes/functions.php
>   on line 4874

**and image to show what the above code displays:**

[image]

Comment: You could use a regular expression to capture the image tags, but won't you be changing the layout with `CSS`?

Comment: @BenPearlKahan I'll be using CSS yes, but I want the Image to be place in a certain element before doing the CSS. That's why I want to split it from the Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [featured images](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails). This featured image will not be included in post content. However, if you already have your images included in post content, then you need to strip the post content down in two parts, as you've said in your question.

I have two functions, one that returns all the images (or any html tag content) from the content and one function that returns the text without the desired tag/images. Both of these functions uses [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

The first function `get_content_without_tag()` returns the content which has been stripped from images. There are two parameters

- `$html` -> The text with images to be stripped, in this case, use `apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() )` to use the post content
- `$tag` -> The name of the tag to strip out, in this case, 'a' as `a` tags hold images

Here is the function

```
function get_content_without_tag( $html, $tag )
{
    // Return false if no html or tag is passed
    if ( !$html || !$tag )
    return false;

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML( $html );

    $dom_x_path = new DOMXPath( $dom );
    while ($node = $dom_x_path->query( '//' . $tag )->item(0)) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild( $node );
    }
    return $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

You would then use this in place of `the_content()` where you would need to display text only, stripping out the complete `<a/>` tag in which the images are as follows

```
echo get_content_without_tag( apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() ), 'a' )
```

The second function, `get_tag_without_text()` returns the content between the desired tag, in your case, images. The parameters are exactly the same as the first function. Here is the function

```
function get_tag_without_text( $html, $tag )
{
    // Return false if no html or tag is passed
    if ( !$html || !$tag )
    return false;

    $document = new DOMDocument();
    $document->loadHTML( $html );  

    $tags = [];
    $elements = $document->getElementsByTagName( $tag );
    if ( $elements ) {
        foreach ( $elements as $element ) {
            $tags[] = $document->saveHtml($element);
        }   
    }   
    return $tags;
}
```

This function returns an array of images should you use `a` tags, so, to display the first image, use the function as follow:

```
$image = get_tag_without_text( apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() ), 'a' );
echo $image[0];
```

### EDIT

The code above is was only tested with `WP_Query` and not with `get_posts`. I have fixed a few bugs in the code above  and also in your code to make it work with `get_posts`

Here is a working example of your code. (*Just remember to update the the functions with the new ones above*)

```
<?php
$args = array( 
    'numberposts' => 2, 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'orderby'     => 'date'
);
$postslist = get_posts( $args );

echo '<ul id="latest_posts">';

    foreach ( $postslist as $post ) {  
        setup_postdata($post); 

        $content = get_content_without_tag( $post->post_content, 'a' );
        $image = get_tag_without_text( $post->post_content, 'a' );

        if ( $content ) 
            echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
        ?> 

        <li>

            <strong>
                <?php the_date(); ?>
            </strong>

            <br />

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"> 
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>

            <?php 
                if ( $image ) { 
                    ?>

                <p>
                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $image[0] ); ?>
                </p>

                    <?php 
                } 
            ?>

        </li>

        <?php 
    } 

echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: I get an unexpected error with '[' with this this line in your example - $tags = [];

Comment: Then your php version is too old. This is short array syntax (`[]`) that only works with php 5.4 and newer. Note, all versions below that is EOL'ed and thus a potential security issue. You can change the short array syntax to the old `array()` syntax, so `$tags = [];` becomes `$tags = array();`

Comment: I'm getting this error - "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_tag_without_text() (previously declared in /hsphere/local/home/poulaum/isosec.co.uk/TestingBlog.php:19) in /hsphere/local/home/poulaum/isosec.co.uk/TestingBlog.php on line 19" - No Idea what i'm doing wrong. I've updated my code above to show you what it's looking like

Comment: You are using the code wrong, the code blocks with the function definitions (blocks 1 and 3) goes into `functions.php` and code block 2 and 4 goes in your loop

Comment: Oops! my bad! I've sorted it now :) Going to test

Comment: So i've tested, I've updated my question with my following code. I've also added an error message I'm getting. - Also could explain to me how I can then put the code from block 2 and 4 into a loop so that I can get a number of my latest blog posts because I want the top 3 blog posts

Comment: I've also added extra task I need to do, I've updated my question to show Task1 and Task2

Comment: You cannot change the question halfway through. I have done enough on this. There is a one question per post policy, so please stick to that. Any additional **tasks** as you call it needs be asked in a **separate** question. Thank you

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks Peter.